# change page url like www.domain.com/products.php?pid=1 to url www.domain.com/products.php?title-of-product-at-pid1

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I click button it takes me to page url like www.domain.com/products.php?pid=1 .I want to change the page url to www.domain.com/products.php?title-of-product-at-pid1-in-database.Please suggest possible ways

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to accomplish this is by using url rewriting. For example on Apache you can use a module called mod_rewrite and you can set custom rules for rewriting URLs. Here is a good article about rewriting URLs.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/